# Android animation imageview 1st rotate and then fadeout for splash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, android-animation

I am trying to make a splash screen for my Android app. I have found many answer related to this question. but none of those worked correctly. I just want to 
1. first fade_in an imageView, then rotate and then  fade_out
or 2. all at the same time. I have tried these code

```
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.animate);

    iv.startAnimation(an);
    an.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Welcome.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
```

and in animate xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">

<rotate
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000"/>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000"/>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `startOffset`. If not specified all elements in your animation sets will all start simultaneously. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="5000" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="5000" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="5000"
        android:startOffset="15000" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, for rotation and fade and fade out,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <alpha
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toAlpha="0.4"/>

    <rotate
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="180"/>

</set>
```